# What are pros and cons of using BigDecimal compared to BigInt for rational numbers?

Tags: java, scala, biginteger, bigdecimal

If I have to design, say, a financial application that uses rational numbers (i.e., numbers with a fractional component), what datatype should I use for internally doing calculations?

I have two options:

1. Use `BigInt` (`BigInteger` in Java) and emulate fixed point arithmetic. I have to keep track of the decimal point separately.
2. Use `BigDecimal` and floating point arithmetic. `BigDecimal` is already a wrapper over BigInt that does most of what I need to do for 1.

I am inclined to use BigDecimal (approach 2) unless someone can give strong arguments for integer arithmetic.

EDIT: In relation to the linked question, I want to know which out of BigDecimal or BigInteger is better, while the other question is more generic and talks about the "best datatype" (which may or may not be out of the two above). In my case, my choice is limited to the two so I cannot use `Currency` type.

Comment: BigDecimal should be fine :)

Comment: Go for `BigDecimal`. Even though you wouldn't need it right now, it is future-proof when your app will expand new features.

Comment: Well, if it's possible, calculate in cents, not dollars. Then you can use simple integers or long integers and format the output lately. Maybe in a trading application performance will become an issue.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Could you elaborate a bit more what problems I could run into in future with `BigInteger`?

Comment: @Oleg edited the question to explain why it may not be a duplicate.

Comment: Integers can be used if you need precision of up to a cent, then you can just increment everything by 100. If in your case you need up to 18 decimals how are you planning on using `BigInteger`?

Comment: Of course you *could* use BigIntegers, but if you need 18 decimals, a Bigdecimal is the best choice. After all, a BigDecimal is generally a scaled BigInteger (or long, depending on the values used).